# 422 Unprocessable Entity with Laravel 8 delete route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a common Larvel 8 project with this codes:

In the **routes/api.php** file:

```php
Route::resources([
    'menu/menu' => Menu\MenuController::class,
]);
```

In the **app/Http/Controllers/Menu/MenuController.php** file:

```php
public function destroy(DestroyMenuRequest $request, Menu $menu) {
    $menu->delete();

    return Response::HTTP_OK;
}
```

In the **DestroyMenuRequest.php** file:

```php
class DestroyMenuRequest extends FormRequest {
    public function authorize() {
        return $this->user()->can('destroy.menu');
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'id' => 'required|integer|exists:menus,id',
        ];
    }
}
```

Then I send a `DELETE` HTTP request to the url `{{domain}}/api/menu/menu/2` and I get back this:

In header 422 (Unprocessable entry), and in the body:

```json
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "id": [
            "The id field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

If I list routes with `php artisan r:l` I see the route with the right controller:

```
DELETE | api/menu/menu/{menu} | menu.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\Menu\MenuController@destroy | api auth:api
```

Any idea what is the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You are auto generating a resource controller. Destroye expects an id in your url. Your route says {menu} which is the hint to the id corresponding to your menu model

Comment: I understand, but how should I use the validator `rules()` in this case?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment above me pointed out, you are generating routes for resource controller.

In your routes list, you can see that the route does not expect an actual ID as the parameter, but rather it expects `Menu` model instance from which Laravel will automatically grab the ID.

Example if you are submitting a form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('menu.destroy', ['menu' => $menuObject]) }}">
@method("DELETE")
...
</form>
```

Where `$menuObject` is of type `Models\Menu`. In other words, it's an instance of `Menu` model you have created